# What did Cersei mean when she said "You flowered little dove"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In one of the episodes of *Game of Thrones*, Sansa woke up to found blood on her bed. She became fearful and started to hide this from Cersei. I didn't understand it. Cersei was cruel to Sansa, but I don't think she wouldn't have given Sansa medical attention. Afterall, Sansa was going to marry Joffrey.

And then, things got more confusing. Instead of calling a maester, Cersei simply said "You flowered little dove". If Sansa had pooped that much blood, that situation could kill her.

I know the meaning of the verb flower. From Google/ Oxford:

> 1. (of a plant) produce flowers; bloom.
>      "Michaelmas daisies can flower as late as October"
> 2. be in or reach an optimum stage of development; develop fully and richly.
>      "she flowered into as striking a beauty as her mother"

I believe second definition has some context, but what has a disease to do with this?

Did Cersei make fun of Sansa by secretly meaning that Sansa lost her youth because of a serious health issue? What exactly did Cersei mean when she said "You flowered little dove"?

Comment: Ohhh... *icky girl stuff*! ☺

Comment: we need to have "the talk"

Comment: Oh... My sweet summer child...

Answer (score 20):

It's a euphemism for having her period. Cersei is the Queen and Sansa is also a noble lady, gently born and of the highest birth. Cersei was not going to speak as if she were a commoner to such. Not to mention, it was Sansa's first period and her reaction made Cersei think Lady Catelyn may not have had "The Talk" with her, which is why a softer touch was needed, even if you disregard the need for courteous speech.

As to why Sansa was afraid, Betrothals turn into marriage once the woman has her first period (Since that is the definition of majority in Westeros). Sansa at that point had seen what Joffrey was and had no wish to be his bride. She was afraid that they will now make her marry Joff and that's why she tried to burn the evidence.

> **SANSA**: No, no! No. Oh, no.
>
> **SERVING GIRL**: It’s all right. Give me that.
>
> **SANSA**: If the queen sees, I can have Joffrey’s children now. Help me flip it over. Where are you going?
>
> **SERVING GIRL**:To tell Her Grace.
>
> **SANSA**: You’ll say nothing to anyone. Do you understand?
>
> [SCENE CHANGES]
>
> **CERSEI**: Your mother might have prepared you. You flowered, my dear. No more.
>
> **SANSA**: My mother told me, but I thought it would be different.
>
> **CERSEI**: In what way?
>
> **SANSA**: I thought it would be less… Less messy.
>
> **CERSEI**: Wait until you birth a child. You’re a woman now. Do you have any idea what that means?
>
> **SANSA**: I’m fit to bear children for the king?
>
> **CERSEI**: A prospect that once delighted you, bringing little princes and princesses into the world, the greatest honour for a
>   queen.
> <sub>*S02E07 - A MAN WITHOUT HONOUR*</sub>

Comment: That was obvious enough for non english speaker to understand :D

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Can confirm. Source: I am a non-native English speaker.

Comment: And as to why Sansa tried to hide it: She knew what it was and feared what is going to happen after that moment

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Ohhh I missed that part of the question. Gonna add it in

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I don't think I ever heard "flowered" used to mean exactly this, except in Game Of Thrones - it's obvious what it means through context. Also, the fact they use such a word to mean having a first period and being capable of becoming pregnant (instead of, say, meaning maturing into an independent and/or beautiful adult) implies a lot about Westeros's expectations of noblewomen and view of marriage as a baby-making political game adults play using their pubescent children as pieces.